# gdal_translate Resample different min max values

Tags: python, gdal-translate, sentinel-2

I tried to resample a Sentinel2 GeoTiff with a 20m resolution to 10m resolution using gdal_translate:

```
result = gdal.Translate(outFile,resampleBandPath,format="GTiff",width=10980,height=10980,resampleAlg="nearest",outputType=gdal.GDT_UInt16)
```

I would like to have one raster value in the 20m repeated four times in the 10m resolutuion output Tiff.

Computing statistics on both images:

```
resample.GetRasterBand(1).GetStatistics(0,1))
old.GetRasterBand(1).GetStatistics(0,1))
```

gives me:

```
[27.0, 8337.0, 799.74556483486, 763.06787190687]
[29.0, 9257.0, 801.11717304189, 768.93310461989]
```

Why is the output image "smoothed"?

Comment: Size of the original is 5490x5490, right?

Comment: Yes, the output raster is 10980x10980.

Comment: I could see the output size from your command, I just wanted to know the original size to be sure that both x and y size are exactly doubled.  Then nearest resampling should really hit all and any original pixel and min and max should remain the same.

Comment: Any idea why it does not work out?